# Search a database table from a DataSet using wildcard symbols

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to compile a query in my dataset which accepts one variable and searches three columns of my SQL Server 08 database table. The query is below but it doesn't ask for the variable. I believe the system perceives the @Query as text since it's enclosed in the single quotes. Any ideas?

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE
((NAME LIKE '%@Query%') OR (Surname LIKE '%@Query%') OR (Telephone LIKE '%@Query%'))
```

I am using the visual dataset editor. 
The way I'm calling it from the VB.NET code is:

```
Dim dtCustomers As DataTable
dtCustomers = Me.CustomerTableAdapter.GetSearchCustomers("myString")
```

Comment: Yes, remove the single quotes but that's not enough. You need to enclose the wild card in the @Query parameter. Could you show the code that use this query?

Comment: NAME LIKE '%' + @Query + '%' etc...

Comment: The way you are using the term DataSet here confuses me.  Is this a .Net DataSet object you are talking about?  If so, then look at the `Select` method on the DataTable in question.  If you are trying to run this select statement on the database server from your VB.Net code, then you should create some SQL Parameter objects for `@Query` and then use the appropriate DataAdapter or DataCommand techniques for fetching the data.

Comment: @bummi I have added the vb code I'm calling the dataset query with as well. You are right. You are answer works. If you could just add your comment as answer I will accept it. Many thanks!

Comment: @bummi you are answer works. Please answer the question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LIKE condition has to contain the content of @Query, not the string '@query'

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE
((NAME LIKE '%'+@Query+'%') OR (Surname LIKE '%*+@Query+'%') OR (Telephone LIKE '%'+@Query+'%'))
```